# how to avoid errors in vscode when making a wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress-theming, visual-studio-code, wordpress-plugin-creation

How to avoid errors due to not having the specific functions of wordpress inside the projet when making a **Wordpress Theme** on **Visual Studio Code** ?

Is there a plugin to download ?

[image: Errors vscode wordpress]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wordpress stubs are included in In VSCode.

You just need to activate it.

If you follow these steps your errors will disapear.

1. Hit the gear icon.(bottom left)
2. Select settings.
3. Search for stubs.
4. Scroll all the way down an click
   on 'Add item'.
5. Hit the dropdown menu.
6. Press w(on your keyboard) and
   scroll to worpress and select it.
7. Hit ok.

Now all the error should disapear.

If not, try to restart VSCode.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using WordPress Stubs https://github.com/php-stubs/wordpress-stubs. The easy way is download this file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/php-stubs/wordpress-stubs/master/wordpress-stubs.php (Wordpress v5.8.1) and paste in your theme.

Answer (score 1):

Open VS Code in the root of the WordPress installation.

You get this error because you are referring to functions that are not in your open files in your editor.

Comment: ah ok... but I don't wan't to open everything, that be too much to display. Isn't there a plugin for vscode that would solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow these steps your errors will disappear.

Click on gear icon > Select settings > Search for stubs > Scroll down an click on 'Add item' > select WordPress > Hit ok

[image]